# Having a problem with hair particles

Tags: hair

So i've been modelling a boardgame figurine, and i wanted to add hair on it. I set the settings and all kinds of stuff, but halfways trough decided to separate the hair into two sections, and each would have different hairlengths.

I separated the hairlayer i duplicated from the head, but when i set the hair length value on one part, the hairlength changes on the other part as well

I dont know why they're still sharing that same number, since i separated them. Can anyone help me explain why this happens and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same preset, they will share the properties. Hit on the little + near the Settings preset to create a new slot for the second one.

[image]